# What is the DFT of $[x_1 -x_2 x_3 -x_4....x_n]$

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, dft

[image]If DFT of $[x_1 x_2 x_3... x_N]$ is $Y(k)$, what is the DFT of $[x_1 -x_2 x_3 -x_4,....x_N]$ in terms of $Y(k)$?
I have tried to formulate it but I cannot get a simplified expression for DFT of modified sequence in terms of $Y(k)$.

[image: the steps of derivation]

Comment: This simply rotates the DFT by half a frame- please show your work thus far to formulate it and we can help you further

Comment: HINT: you should first express [x1,-x2,x3,-x4...,xN] in terms of [x1,x2,x3,...,xN], and then use a DFT property (if it exists) that corresponds to such a relation...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Consider a factor 2 down-sampled sequence : $\tilde{x} = \{x_1, x_3, x_5, ...\}$ and consider another sequence which is circular shifted by $-1$ sample and downsampled by a factor of 2 : $\hat{x} = \{ x_2, x_4, x_6, ...\}$. Observe that the required sequence is difference of $\tilde{x}$ and $\hat{x}$. Each of the DFT can be computed by observation using properties.